# how Respond to BroadCast receiver based on Application Running status.?

Tags: android

I have a registered Broad Cast receiver in my app to store USB connected/disconnected state in Shared Preferences. Its working Fine.

Now i wanted to perform a task immediately if USB connected and my application is running. how can i do this?

If my application is not running , i ll perform the task in my first activity based on the Shared Preference value.

Please give some ideas to do this..

Comment: It is as simple as invoking your task/method in the onReceive() of your receiver. Are you looking for anything special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have paste some code which shows how to check for running services [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452466/how-to-determine-if-an-android-service-is-running-in-the-foreground/6452570#6452570).
If you looking for activity use RunningTaskInfo instead of RunningServicesInfo.