# startForeground() does not show my Notification

Tags: android, service, foreground

I am trying to make my `Service` running in foreground. I tried to use [this example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) (please look for the section "*Running a Service in the Foreground*"), but `startForeground()` does not actually show my notification. And no exceptions is thrown. To make it shown, I need to use `NotificationManager` like [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) explained. With `NotificationManager` my notification works, but i'm not sure that my `Service` is foreground after this "silent" call to `startForeground()`.

What can be wrong?

**EDIT**: I just tested [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer) that should demonstrate `startForeground()`, but it does not work! I use API v7.0, I tested it both on emulator and real device (SE Xperia Neo). Notification does not appear.

**EDIT2**: if i try to call `setForeground()` then i got a warning `setForeground: ignoring old API call`.

I also tried to use `startForegroundCompat()` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/), but effect is absolutelly the same. I check if my service is foreground using `ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452466/how-to-determine-if-an-android-service-is-running-in-the-foreground), and I see that my service is **not** foreground.

Comment: Since you elected to not provide source code, it will be difficult to help you directly. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer) that uses `startForeground()` successfully.

Comment: I did not provide source code because of my code is exactly the same as in example i provided: http://goo.gl/xXIvc . Thanks for the sample project.

Comment: I tested this sample project, it does not work! I use API v7.0, i tested it both on emulator and real device (SE Xperia Neo). Notification does not appear.

Comment: The sample project works perfectly fine -- I just re-tested it on a Nexus One, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S, HTC Desire S, and the "API v7.0" emulator. To start the service and display the `Notification`, press the "Start the Player" button.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your time. And, of course, i pressed the "Start the Player" button =). Very strange, but it does not work for me on SE Xperia Neo and and API v7.0 emulator. Tomorrow i will test it on some kind of Acer, but i think the problem is in some different place, but i have absolutely no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I just noticed that `startForeground()` doesn't show the notification icon if the `id` parameter is set to `0`...

```
startForeground(0, notification); // Doesn't work...

startForeground(1, notification); // Works!!!
```

I hope that it could help someone stuck on this.

Comment: and yet the documentation is woefully vague about what this id value even does... I am totally frustrated with the (IMO) poor documentation -_-

Comment: And I had **123** which didn't work, changed to 1 and it works!

Comment: @HerrGrumps The docs have been updated and now have a warning: "The integer ID you give to startForeground() must not be 0." (developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Better later than never =P

Comment: Shaw's answer could also be an explanation for the notification not showing up.

Comment: Note that this bug in Android has since been fixed.

Comment: Do not use too big integers like 1337 , 13377331 , 137 . Just use 0x3, 0x1

Comment: @RavindranathAkila I also used 123, but changing to 1 still doesn't work :(

Comment: I was using "0" and have been trying to fix this for days now. Android always surprises me, in a bad way :(

Comment: F%#$ me! .... This had me stumped for almost a day

Answer (score 51):

in addition to the best answer. 
you should also check that have you called `setSmallIcon`.
On my android phone, I cannot get what I expected without calling `setSmallIcon`

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Thanks for this. This isn't mentioned as required in the services documentation, but it certainly should be!

Comment: <Rant>Android's official documentation covers 10% of the subject.</Rant>

Comment: +1 This answer is so useful, I spent all day trying to figure why the stupid notification didn't behave properly...

Comment: This was my issue as well; without `setSmallIcon`, the notification just said '<app name> is running'. Thanks for saving me time and pain!

Comment: you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Is your service a started service or a bound service? I had the same issue with a bound service, but starting the service before binding it allowed me to call `startForeground(int, notification)` with and have the notification show up.

Comment: for desired-to-be-bounded `Service` best option would be to show notification/start foreground in `onCreate`, it will be called before binding (`onStartCommand` will be called soon and wiil get initial `Intent`, that too late for notifying/foreground). thanks for clue!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old thread, but I'd like to add what I just learned which is not mentioned yet:

It is possible that a `Service` is still alive after `stopSelf()` is called because there are `Activity` that have bound to the `Service`. As a matter of fact, the `startForeground()` is just not going to show the notification nor giving any exception in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

in my case there was no notification after `startForeground(...)` invoke because I used only `.setSubText(...)` for setting the message of it (because it is rendered with smaller font on most of devices). But some of devices Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 won't show any notification if You not set message by using `.setContentText(...)`.

Hope that will help someone

Answer (score 0):

DMitry. I have just suffered your problem and found the cause.

If your app is changing state of a COMPONENT `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting())` Android removes the service from foregraound and its notification icon.

[Bug reported at Nov, 2011](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21635)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my app do not change state of a COMPONENT, so this might be some other reason.