# Uploading files in an Android service

Tags: android, service, intentservice

What is the best way of letting an Android app upload a potentially large file to a server at a request from the user?

I'm currently using an `IntentService`, in which I call `startForeground` and update the notification progress periodically, but the service randomly gets killed by the system after about a minute or so.

Here is the relevant code from `onHandleIntent` :

```
class BeamService extends IntentService("SSH Beam") {

  override def onHandleIntent(intent: Intent) = {

    ...

    // Start the notification
    startForeground(0,
      builder
      .setTicker("Starting transfer")
      .setContentTitle(filename)
      .setContentText("Starting transfer")
      .setOngoing(true).build
    )

    // Create the session and the monitor
    val session = server.createSession(auth)
    implicit val monitor = Monitor(filename, size)

    // Send the file
    try {
      session.connect
      session.cd(destination)
      session.put(filename, is)
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => {
        notificationManager.notify(0,
          builder.setProgress(0, 0, false)
                 .setTicker("Transfer failed")
                 .setContentText(e.getMessage)
                 .build
        )
        e.printStackTrace
      }
    } finally {
      session.disconnect
      is.close
    }

    stopForeground(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: You might consider posting the code for the service. Also, bear in mind that `IntentService` has its own background thread (so don't fork your own) and that it does not keep the device awake (see my `WakefulIntentService` for one that does).

Comment: I added the `onHandleIntent` code. Any ideas? Should I put the service in a separate process, or is it fine to let it stay in the same process as the activity that started it?

Comment: "Any ideas?" -- uh, well, that's not Java code, so I'm not real sure what you're doing there. "Should I put the service in a separate process, or is it fine to let it stay in the same process as the activity that started it?" -- having it in the same process should be fine.

Comment: It's in Scala, so more or less the same, without boilerplate and parentheses. I'm not getting any kind of exception from the service, just "service died" in the LogCat, followed by "scheduling restart", so I assume the system just killed it even though it was in the foreground.

Comment: Yeah, that's not supposed to happen, particularly with `startForeground()`. Not sure what's happening to you.

Comment: Hm. Now it works. using `notify` in my progress monitor caused the service to exit the foreground state. Weird to have to call `startForeground` again to update the notification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to implement that properly :

- Do *not* use the `notify` method from the `NotificationManager` while you are in foreground. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528288/how-do-i-update-the-notification-text-for-a-foreground-service-in-android?rq=1), you have to use `startForeground` again if you want to update the notification. *(This was causing my service to get killed by the system)*
- There's a [weird quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725909/startforeground-does-not-show-my-notification) in `startForeground` that makes it *not* show notifications if the ID is 0.
- Finally, I should have thought about it, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android?rq=1) gives a nice in-depth answer on how to check if the service is indeed in foreground.

*(The fantastic flying network monitor from the [System Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.systemmonitor&hl=en) app also helped me a lot to check if the upload was still running while I was starting other apps to try and trigger the "service died" message)*

Comment: Hey, the "System Monitor" app link is broken! Can you please correct it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons to use startForeground, but I can't for the life of me think of a reason to use startForeground on an IntentService! An IntentService should be used to do long-running tasks on a background thread, without interruption, from which you want persistent results.

Comment: And... that's exactly what I want to do. If I don't use ` startForeground` the service gets killed by the system halfway through the download.

Comment: Thinking back about it, you might actually be right, especially about the *without interruption* part. I'm trying to find a way to cancel the download halfway through with a notification action button, and according to the docs the `IntentService` will not receive another intent before it has processed the download. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intent-service?rq=1) I may be able to use a `BroadcastReceiver` thought.