# Android Firebase Notification if Application is opened

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured the FCM for my 3° application android but in this case the notification is received only if application is closed or background, when app is running nothing appears.

This is my .FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());    

    }    

    private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        Intent showFullQuoteIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        showFullQuoteIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        // both of these approaches now work: FLAG_CANCEL, FLAG_UPDATE; the uniqueInt may be the real solution.
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, showFullQuoteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, showFullQuoteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(body)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(m, notification);

    }
}
```

Called in:

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Please can you help me? FCM is linked to my firebase account and i send notification from firebase site...

FCM Log:

```
D/FA: Logging event (FE): notification_foreground(_nf), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=fcm, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Home, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8508869816157962301, message_device_time(_ndt)=0, message_name(_nmn)=test, message_time(_nmt)=1521054559, message_id(_nmid)=5215133478455582605}]
```

I have use some code like:
[Notification not showing in Android 8 Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-android-8-oreo)
And Guidelines from Google: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

But if application is opened notification not received but logged in console..

Comment: Nothing in the code you show appears to be related to your issue. I think this is specific to your device and/or android build

Comment: Tested on device emulator and 2 real device... same issue, with other the 1° and 2° application notification working fine =(

Comment: Log say only this:
W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case

Comment: Try using notificationmanager compat instead of notification manager

Comment: Nothing change =(

Comment: try using `this` as context parameter for your builder constructor call

Comment: Nothing =( I'm really desperate

Comment: Are the devices running Oreo?

Comment: Yes all device tested with oreo =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android foreground service notification not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658923/android-foreground-service-notification-not-showing)

Comment: I try now but if the problem is this why old application working fine? I have used the same code..

Comment: Because the way the OS works changes considerably when the major version is increased. You should take this into consideration.

Comment: Nothing change testet with some code, channel id and other instruction from guidelines of google =(

Comment: If i change API target from 26 to 25 notification working fine =(

Comment: You channel is empty, did you think about that? It's probably related, you now know for sure the reason of your problem has to do with Oreo, so go and research, try new things, and share the knowledge when you manage to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved with this code:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channesl_01";
            CharSequence name = "NEWS";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            Intent showFullQuoteIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            showFullQuoteIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, showFullQuoteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext(), "")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setSound(notificationSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .build();

            mNotificationManager.notify(m, notification);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent showFullQuoteIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            showFullQuoteIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, showFullQuoteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setSound(notificationSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
        }
    }
```