# Why Doesn't Work "setOngoing" or "setAutoCancel" in startForeground?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working an android project. I want to send notification when app is killed. I did it but, I can't remove notification when slide left or click notification. I try use

> .setOngoing(false)

and

> .setAutoCancel(true).

But, It doesn't work for me.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Service.this, Message.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Service.this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Service.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
```

I succes when use NotificationCompat.Builder, but startForeground don't accept that. What can I do?

Comment: add permission in manifest.xml file `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` hope its work.

Comment: @HardikVasani I added it but still doesn't work.

Comment: [check this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634187/2794507)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Order to cancel or swipe foreground notification

ie
`.setOngoing(false)` and  `.setAutoCancel(true)`

> **You will have to kill the Service using `stopService()**

**NOTE**:-
*The user is not allowed to swipe away a notification generated by an ongoing foreground service.*