# Notification startForeground() not working the second time

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I am creating a notification using service class. It works fine with below android O, but for higher versions, the notification is shown for the first time and if I try to show it for the second time it's not showing. Below is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.e("inside here", "inside ");
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentTitle(strLiveBroadcast)
            .setContentText(strAppName)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            .addAction(icon, "pause", action)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_white, "stop", stopAction)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(service.getMediaSession().getSessionToken())
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                    .setShowCancelButton(true)
                    .setCancelButtonIntent(stopAction));

    service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

This is working completely fine in lower versions.

Comment: Please post this method code: `onMessageReceived`

Comment: it can be help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093260/notification-not-showing-in-oreo

Comment: It works for the first time even in higher versions but doesn't work the second time.

Comment: @Ali I am not clear what you are trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

`startForeground()` doesn't not work with notifications If the `NOTIFICATION_ID` parameter is set to 0 OR else you need to add Random Id logic every time you call it.

```
startForeground(0, notification); // Doesn't work...

startForeground(1, notification); // Works!!!
```

I hope this will work!!

Comment: `NOTIFICATION_ID ` is 555 in my case

Comment: Okay, you can achieve this by follow this buddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658923/android-foreground-service-notification-not-showing

Comment: This exact solutions of your problem, Please check it @bhaskar

Comment: I have clearly mentioned it works for the first time but doesn't work second time.
Also i have added the condition for higher version and also added permission in my menifest file