# Notification is not displayed in notification drawer if app is in foreground

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a notification into my app using Firebase cloud messaging and it's working fine. However, when I send a notification and if my app is in the foreground, the notification will not show in the notification tray. The notification only shows in the notification tray if my app is in the background.

Below is my code:

```
public class Notifications extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @ServerTimestamp
    Date time;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private boolean isNotificationMatching = false;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                sendNotificationAPI26(remoteMessage);

            else
                sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        isNotificationMatching = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationFragment", "showNotifications");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String title = data.get("title");

        mFirestore.collection("notifications").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (document.getData().get("id").equals(id)) {
                            isNotificationMatching = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isNotificationMatching) {
                        postDataToFirebaseServer(data);
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti.notify(new Random().nextInt(), builder.build());
    }

    private void postDataToFirebaseServer(Map<String, String> data) {

        Map<String, Object> postDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        postDataMap.put("title", data.get("title"));

        postDataMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());


        mFirestore.collection("notifications").add(postDataMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
//                Toast.makeText(getA.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                String error = e.getMessage();
//                Toast.makeText(Testing.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendNotificationAPI26(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationFragment", "showNotifications");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String title = data.get("title");

        mFirestore.collection("notifications").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (document.getData().get("id").equals(id)) {
                            isNotificationMatching = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isNotificationMatching) {
                        postDataToFirebaseServer(data);
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

        NotificationHelper helper;
        Notification.Builder builder;

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        helper = new NotificationHelper(this);
        builder = helper.getLootBoxNotification(title, defaultSoundUri);
        helper.getManager().notify(new Random().nextInt(), builder.build());
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android foreground service notification not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658923/android-foreground-service-notification-not-showing) & https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451582/3974530

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Here you have set is as

```
setAutoCancel(true);
```

This method will cancel all the notification while your app is in foreground.
Set it to false.