# How to rebind to foreground service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

A foreground service is started and immediately bound to. Is there a way to know whether the serivce has been stopped or is still running after an activity restart. The safe way would be to execute `startService` anyway, but is there a cleaner one?

Comment: no, there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6452570/5457878

To check if your service is still running. You can call this method in your `onResume()` or `onCreate()`, and if it is not running, I would restart it.

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName){
    boolean serviceRunning = false;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = am.getRunningServices(50);
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = i
                .next();

        if(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceName)){
            serviceRunning = true;

            if(runningServiceInfo.foreground)
            {
                //service run in foreground
            }
        }
    }
    return serviceRunning;
}
```